# EE 1.10 search results broken

Tags: search, enterprise-1.10

This is a really weird one so don't know if anyone else has seen this but any help gratefully received.

We are running on EE 1.10 and have just added a load of new products.  When we use the quick search for a product it shows up but if we try to add to the basket it sometimes fails to add then 404's and the product will not show up in the search results again.  The 404 only seems to be when there is a single search result and when there are multiple results the page refreshes to the search results but the product we have just added is removed from the search results.  Inventory is fine so the product is in stock etc.

We've had to remove the add to basket action from the list.phtml template for the time being but obviously want to be able to reinstate it but can't while this is continuing.

My local dev version of the site was doing this so I cleared out the search tables and rebuilt the full text index (this occurs with both like and combine searches)

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you using SOLR? Did you manually `clear out the search tables`?

Comment: Two other questions potentially of value here are: a) how are you importing the products? — b) what is your caching setup?

Comment: Yep, I've cleared out search tables manually and no we are not using SOLR, just the normal Magento product search.  Products are imported using normal Dataflow import.  Caching is a mix of APC, Magento cache in the DB and we have the Magento compiler switched on.

Comment: Right, it looks like this had to do with Predictive Intent (not their fault!).  Their Personal Search was supposed to have been turned off a while ago by previous developers but it had only been done in Global scope not store View.

Comment: @RichardCleverley please mark your predictive intent solution as the answer.

Comment: No worries, I'll add it as an answer and mark it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it looks like this had to do with Predictive Intent (not their fault!). Their Personal Search was supposed to have been turned off a while ago by previous developers but it had only been done in Global scope not store View.